# How to get Visualforce to output Excel with column freezing (panes)

Tags: visualforce, data-export

I'm trying to get a Visualforce page to output to an Excel file that contains column freeze points.
Is this possible?

The "plain" Excel is working via: 
contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#AccountContactsTable.xls"

But not sure how/if to do the row/col freezing/locking bit.

Anyone know-hows?

Comment: You can also just save a plain HTML file with a table and load that in Excel... maybe there's a style class or something you can leverage in there to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks but CSS doesn't seem to do it when it comes to freezing/locking.  I have been using CSS to style cells etc.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I bumped into a post where they do it through asp.net maybe that can be helpful for you?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185928/how-can-i-create-a-freeze-pane-in-excel-when-exporting-via-asp-net-using-xml

I know you can do it inside visual force using Jquery but that is then without the exporting to excel.

http://brentmuir.com/projects/freezeheader/